# Trac XML-RPC Plugin: the number of tickets

Tags: python, rpc, trac

Can I get the number of tickets using the Trac XML-RPC Plugin, without requiring all tickets from the server?

The trac API describes parameter "format=count", but it does not work for me ...
I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import xmlrpclib
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("https://user:password@trac-server/login/xmlrpc")
multicall = xmlrpclib.MultiCall(server)
for t in server.ticket.query('status=new&format=count&max=3'):
    print t
```

... but get only ticket numbers, not the number of it.

I can count so:

```
import xmlrpclib
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("https://user:password@trac-server/login/xmlrpc")
multicall = xmlrpclib.MultiCall(server)
print( server.ticket.query('max=0') )
```

... but I think it's not a very optimal way, because this method loads all data from the server.

Is there a way to get the number of tickets without requiring a complete list and counting it?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a semantical error. Use commas instead of ampersand to separate the format from the query condition. The `max=3` parameter is not useful here. Then your query will look like this:

```
for t in server.ticket.query('status=new,format=count'):
    print t
```

and the result is just a number telling the count under the given condition `status=new`. Change the condition by adding more terms via ampersand, e.g. `status=new&owner=joe`.

Comment: No, it does not work. It seems to me that the trac is trying to apply a filter status='new,format=count' or something like that.